# Creating and using a Model Class

Tags: android

I am learning and trying to strengthen my android app development skills. So after some learning I am trying to build a mini-inventory app with Firebase database that allows shop owner sell from the app if they need to. So i created a model class "Product.java" to have fields including product characteristics, inventory and sales management because I want to be able to update product quantity as the seller sells product and be able to add a dashboard to display revenue from sales and profit. See the class bellow, is this a good idea?

```
public class Product implements Serializable {
private String id;
private String sku; // newly added
private String name;
private String description;
private String costPrice;
private String sellingPrice;
private double discount; // newly added
private String initialQuantity; // changed to int
private int currentQuantity; // newly added
private int quantitySold; // newly added
private String orderQuantity; // newly added
private double stockValue; // newly added
private double amountSold; // newly added
private double profit; // newly added
private String customerName;
private String customerEmail;
private String customerPhone;
private String imageUrl;
private String imageName;

// Constructors
public Product() {
}

public Product(String id, String sku, String name, String description, String costPrice, String sellingPrice, double discount, String initialQuantity, int currentQuantity, int quantitySold, String orderQuantity, double stockValue, double amountSold, double profit, String customerName, String customerEmail, String customerPhone, String imageUrl, String imageName) {
    this.setId(id);
    this.setSku(sku);
    this.setName(name);
    this.setDescription(description);
    this.setCostPrice(costPrice);
    this.setSellingPrice(sellingPrice);
    this.setDiscount(discount);
    this.setInitialQuantity(initialQuantity);
    this.setCurrentQuantity(currentQuantity);
    this.setQuantitySold(quantitySold);
    this.setOrderQuantity(orderQuantity);
    this.setStockValue(stockValue);
    this.setAmountSold(amountSold);
    this.setProfit(profit);
    this.setCustomerName(customerName);
    this.setCustomerEmail(customerEmail);
    this.setCustomerPhone(customerPhone);
    this.setImageUrl(imageUrl);
    this.setImageName(imageName);
```

// Getters and Setters
....

// Should I also add the inventory management methods here?

// Should I add the sellProduct method here too???
}

Please be a bit explicit in your response, I am still a new learner

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest removing details about the customer; this is not about a `Product`. For matters of stock levels, I would suggest a separate `Inventory` class to capture collections of `Product`s.

Comment: thanks a lot @codebod I see your point, I will remove those now and based on your suggestion it would also be good to separate the sales into another class as well right?

Comment: @codebod the Inventory class and sales classes should extend the product classes right? or what do you think?

Comment: No, I don't think one should extend the other. They are different things.  An `Inventory` is not a specific type of `Product`, nor the other way round for that matter.

Comment: @codebod that's true but how then will I track and update product counts in the inventory   class?

Comment: The Inventory would contain a collection of your products, e.g. `ArrayList<Product>`.

Comment: @codebod thanks, I really appreciate your help, let me try to put all that into practice and see how it goes. I'd probably let you know how it goes if that's okay.